# Баг .animate(), проблемы со скролом.

Tags: jquery, javascript, прокрутка, события

Суть проблемы, строка:

```
$('.previewblock').animate({ left: "-=200" }, 300);
```

или

```
$('.previewblock').animate({ left: "+=200" },300);
```

Срабатывает несколько раз минуя условие:

```
if (leftint > diff)
```

или

```
 if (leftint < 0)
```

Точнее проверяет только первый раз, а дальше исполняет анимацию N-е количество раз (сколько крутнул колесико) 
Code:

```
// проверяем наводку на необходимый блок
    $('.previewblock').mouseenter(function () {
        hoverpreview = true;
    });
    $('.previewblock').mouseleave(function () {
        hoverpreview = false;
    });
    //Обработка мышки
    function addHandler(object, event, handler) {
        if (object.addEventListener) {
            object.addEventListener(event, handler, false);
        }
        else if (object.attachEvent) {
            object.attachEvent('on' + event, handler);
        }
        else alert("error");
    }

    addHandler(window, 'DOMMouseScroll', wheel);
    addHandler(window, 'mousewheel', wheel);
    addHandler(document, 'mousewheel', wheel);
    //Реализация скрола
    function wheel(event) {
        var delta;
        event = event || window.event;

        if (event.wheelDelta) {
            delta = event.wheelDelta / 120;

            if (window.opera) delta = -delta;
        }
        else if (event.detail) {
            delta = -event.detail / 3;
        }

      if (event.preventDefault) event.preventDefault();
            event.returnValue = false;
    //проверяем, наведена ли мышка
            if (hoverpreview == true) {
//если скролим вниз
                if (delta < 0) {
//находим границу, мах значение сдвига.
                    var leftstr = $('.previewblock').css("left");
                    leftstr = leftstr.substring(0, leftstr.length - 2);
                    var leftint = parseInt(leftstr);
                    var previewint = $('.previewblock').width();
                    var sliderint = $('.viewport').width();
                    var diff = sliderint - previewint;
//если текущий сдвиг в пределах нормы
                    if (leftint > diff) {
    //анимируем сдвиг
                        $('.previewblock').animate({ left: "-=200" }, 300);
                    }
                }
    // если крутим вниз
                else {
                    var leftstr = $('.previewblock').css("left");
                    leftstr = leftstr.substring(0, leftstr.length - 2);
                    var leftint = parseInt(leftstr);
                    if (leftint < 0) {
                        $('.previewblock').animate({ left: "+=200" },300);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

Comment: когда делаете относительную анимацию, ставьте перед ней .finish()

Answer (score 1):

[[@Shadower](/users/22586/shadower)](/users/22586/shadower), для начала:

```
$('.previewblock').finish().animate(/* ... */);
```

И не плохо бы пример сделать на [jsfiddle.net](http://jsfiddle.net/), а то приходится догадываться, что и как там у вас.